# Which control to use in MenuItem? (Fluent Ribbon)

Tags: c#, wpf, fluent-ribbon

I'm using Fluent Ribbon and I use ApplicationMenu for Ribbon's Menu. I want to create an ApplicationMenu look like this:

[image]

Right now I'm using a StackPanel to create the item which inside the red circle in the image above.

So I wonder if there a better way to create that? Is Fluent Ribbon support a control like that? If yes, what control is that and how can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

To create a header for some content, you can try HeaderedContentControl. Eg;

```
<HeaderedContentControl Header="_JPEG Picture" Canvas.Left="220" Canvas.Top="116">
   <DockPanel Margin="-50 0 0 0">
         <Image Source="img/penguins.jpg" Width="50" Height="50"/>
         <TextBlock Text="save a picture"/>
   </DockPanel>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

For keyboard mnemonics, you can provide template for Header like :

```
<HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label Content="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=HeaderedContentControl}}"/> 
    </DataTemplate>
</HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate>
```